# Python periodic task using oslo service

Tags: python, oslo

I am trying to run a method periodically(60 seconds). I am using oslo service to do so. Below is the snippet.

```
import time
from oslo_service import periodic_task

class MyClass(periodic_task.PeriodicTasks):
    def __init__(self):
        super(periodic_task.PeriodicTasks, self).__init__()

    @periodic_task.periodic_task
    def hello(self):
        print "hello"

    def sleeptime(self):
        time.sleep(5000)

myobj = MyClass()
myobj.hello()
myobj.sleeptime()
```

"hello" gets printed just once. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Would you consider using `import time` and `time.sleep(seconds)` at the end of your hello function?

Comment: the oslo_service's periodic task by default takes 60 seconds. I think i need not do that. I went ahead and tried what you suggested. Does not work that way